# How to perform Ctrl+multiple mouse clicks operation using Ruby with Selenium Watir-webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I came across a difficulty where I have to perform Ctrl+mouse click operation using watir-webdriver with Ruby

In my web application application I have to select multiple options using Ctrl key plus mouse clicks (random options not all options). I could see multiple solutions using C# or Java. But I couldn't find any solution using Ruby and Watir-webdriver. Can anyone help me?

I have tried using the below code
 regionsArray=['Airlines', 'Biotechnology', 'Financial Conglomerates', 'Food Retail',  'Restaurants', 'Savings Banks and Tobacco']

```
      oPage.action.key_down(:control)

      puts "hello2"
      regionsArray.each { |x|
        indXpath="//div[@id=('options-tree-region')]//div[text()='#{x}']"
        indText = UtilsCommon.GetElementWithXpath(oPage, indXpath, 10, true)

          if indText!= false 
            indText.click
    end
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the control behaves similar to the jQuery UI selectable and will use their [demo](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/selectable/default.html) as an example.

The demo page is:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">

    <style>
      #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
      #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
      #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
      #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
      #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ol class="ui-selectable" id="selectable">
       <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">Item 1</li>
       <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">Item 2</li>
       <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">Item 3</li>
       <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">Item 4</li>
       <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">Item 5</li>
       <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">Item 6</li>
       <li class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">Item 7</li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Option 1 - Using ActionBuilder**

As you noticed, you could call down to the Selenium-WebDriver ActionBuilder to press control and then click the elements. I am guessing that your code did not work was because the `perform` method was never called for the action. For the demo page, to hold control and click each li would be:

```
# Press control (note the call to 'perform' the action)
browser.driver.action.key_down(:control).perform

# Click the elements
browser.lis.each(&:click)
```

So that control is pressed and then released at the end, you could also do:

```
action = browser.driver.action
action.key_down(:control)
browser.lis.each { |li| action.click(li.wd) }
action.key_up(:control)
action.perform
```

**Option 2 - Using Modifiers for Click**

An alternative solution would be to use Watir's click method with modifiers. The modifiers can be used to tell Watir to hold down certain keys while clicking an element. For example, the following will press control while clicking each li:

```
browser.lis.each do |li|
  li.click(:control)
end
```

Note that this is technically a different user behaviour than that in Option 1. In Option 1, the control button is held while all lis were clicked. In contrast Option 2 will press the control button, click the element, release the control button and then repeat for the next element. Depending on the application's implementation, it may or may not care about the difference.

Comment: When we can use 'hold' and 'release' methods

Comment: Sorry @Shiv, I do not understand your comment. Can you please clarify/elaborate?